# Spring Boot - Rabbitmq java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I have been working on a banking project. I have a problem that is about RabbitMQ and Docker.

I have two microservices that are called query and command. Both of them **can not connect to my RabbitMq container**. I have been trying to solve this problem, but I could not.

I can succesfully connect and open http://localhost:15672/#/ after docker compose.

When I run docker compose up, **account-cmd** and **account-query** services not running on the browser. Here is my docker-compose.yml file.

```
        version: "3.4"

        services:

          customerdb:
            container_name: customerdb
            image: postgres
            environment:
             POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-postgres}
             POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
            volumes:
              - ./customer/postgres_init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgres_init.sql
            ports:
              - "5432:5432"
            restart: unless-stopped

          querydb:
            container_name: querydb
            image: postgres
            environment:
              POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
              POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-postgres}
            volumes:
              - ./account.query/postgres_init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgres_init.sql
            ports:
              - "5433:5432"
            restart: unless-stopped

          rabbitmq:
            container_name: "bank_rabbitmq"
            image: "rabbitmq:3.8-management"
            hostname: "rabbitmq"
            environment:
              RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "guest"
              RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "guest"
              RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: "/"
            ports:
              - "15672:15672"
              - "5672:5672"

          cmddb:
            container_name: "cmddb"
            image: mongo
            restart: always
            ports:
                - "27017:27017"

          customer-service:
            image: bank/customer-service-api
            container_name: customer-service
            build:
              context: ./customer
              dockerfile: Dockerfile
            ports:
              - "5000:5000"
            depends_on:
              - customerdb
            environment:
              - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://customerdb:5432/customerdb
              - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
              - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=postgres

          account-cmd:
            image: bank/account-cmd-service-api
            container_name: account-cmd-service
            build:
              context: ./account.cmd
              dockerfile: Dockerfile
            ports:
              - "5002:5002"
            depends_on:
              - cmddb
              - rabbitmq
            environment:
              - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST=cmddb
              - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT=27017
              - SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_DATABASE=accountcmdb
              - SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
              - SPRING_RABBITMQ_PORT=5672
              - SPRING_RABBITMQ_USERNAME=guest
              - SPRING_RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=guest

          account-query:
            image: bank/account-query-service-api
            container_name: account-query-service
            build:
              context: ./account.query
              dockerfile: Dockerfile
            ports:
              - "5003:5003"
            depends_on:
              - querydb
              - rabbitmq
            environment:
              - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://querydb:5433/accountingdb
              - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
              - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=postgres
              - SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
              - SPRING_RABBITMQ_PORT=5672
              - SPRING_RABBITMQ_USERNAME=guest
              - SPRING_RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=guest

        volumes:
          customerdb:
          cmddb:
          querydb:
```

Here is my RabbitMQConfig on spring boot.

```
    package com.bankingsolution.account.query.configuration;

    import com.bankingsolution.common.constants.Contants;
    import org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding;
    import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
    import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
    import org.springframework.amqp.core.TopicExchange;
    import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListenerConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory;
    import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
    import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
    import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar;
    import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
    import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;
    import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory;

    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    @Configuration
    public class RabbitMQConfig implements RabbitListenerConfigurer {

        @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.host}")
        private String hostName;

        @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.username}")
        private String userName;

        @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.password}")
        private String password;

        @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.port}")
        private int port;

        @Bean
        public TopicExchange exchange() {
            return new TopicExchange(Contants.TOPIC_KEY);
        }

        @Bean
        Queue accountOpenedQueue() {
            return new Queue(Contants.AccountOpenedTopic);
        }

        @Bean
        Queue fundsDepositedQueue() {
            return new Queue(Contants.FundsDepositedTopic);
        }

        @Bean
        Queue fundsWithdrawnQueue() {
            return new Queue(Contants.FundsWithDrawnTopic);
        }

        @Bean
        Queue transactionCreatedQueue() {
            return new Queue(Contants.TransactionCreatedTopic);
        }

        @Bean
        Queue transactionFailedQueue() {
            return new Queue(Contants.TransactionFailedTopic);
        }

        @Bean
        public List<Binding> binding() {
            return Arrays.asList(
                    BindingBuilder.bind(accountOpenedQueue()).to(exchange()).with(Contants.AccountOpenedTopic),
                    BindingBuilder.bind(fundsDepositedQueue()).to(exchange()).with(Contants.FundsDepositedTopic),
                    BindingBuilder.bind(fundsWithdrawnQueue()).to(exchange()).with(Contants.FundsWithDrawnTopic),
                    BindingBuilder.bind(transactionCreatedQueue()).to(exchange()).with(Contants.TransactionCreatedTopic),
                    BindingBuilder.bind(transactionFailedQueue()).to(exchange()).with(Contants.TransactionFailedTopic));
        }

        @Bean
        public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
            return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
        }


        @Bean
        public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
            SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();

            factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
            return factory;
        }

        @Bean
        public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
            CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
            connectionFactory.setHost(this.hostName);
            connectionFactory.setVirtualHost("/");
            connectionFactory.setUsername(this.userName);
            connectionFactory.setPassword(this.password);
            connectionFactory.setPort(this.port);
            return connectionFactory;
        }


        @Override
        public void configureRabbitListeners(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
            registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(myHandlerMethodFactory());
        }

        @Bean
        public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory myHandlerMethodFactory() {
            DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory factory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
            factory.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
            return factory;
        }
    }
```

Here is sample error on Docker for a microservice.

```
            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueInfo(RabbitAdmin.java:463) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:447) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.attemptDeclarations(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1925) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1906) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.initialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1349) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1195) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

            at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]

            at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

            at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

            at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

            at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

            at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

            at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60) ~[amqp-client-5.13.1.jar!/:5.13.1]

            at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1223) ~[amqp-client-5.13.1.jar!/:5.13.1]

            at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1173) ~[amqp-client-5.13.1.jar!/:5.13.1]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connectAddresses(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:640) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:615) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:565) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            ... 12 common frames omitted


        2022-03-22 01:07:40.006  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#4-3] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [rabbitmq:5672]

        2022-03-22 01:07:40.006  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#4-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [rabbitmq:5672]

        2022-03-22 01:07:40.007 ERROR 1 --- [ntContainer#4-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).


        org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:602) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:724) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:252) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2175) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2148) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2128) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueInfo(RabbitAdmin.java:463) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:447) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.attemptDeclarations(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1925) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1906) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.initialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1349) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1195) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

            at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]

            at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

            at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

            at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

            at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

            at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

            at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60) ~[amqp-client-5.13.1.jar!/:5.13.1]

            at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1223) ~[amqp-client-5.13.1.jar!/:5.13.1]

            at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1173) ~[amqp-client-5.13.1.jar!/:5.13.1]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connectAddresses(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:640) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:615) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:565) ~[spring-rabbit-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]

            ... 12 common frames omitted


        2022-03-22 01:07:40.008  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#4-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [rabbitmq:5672]

        2022-03-22 01:07:40.023  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.b.account.query.QueryApplication       : Started QueryApplication in 8.535 seconds (JVM running for 9.399)

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.965  WARN 1 --- [ntContainer#0-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.965  WARN 1 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.966  WARN 1 --- [ntContainer#0-3] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.966  WARN 1 --- [ntContainer#0-4] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.969  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#0-3] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@27755487: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.969  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#0-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@2e5b7fba: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.969  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#0-4] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@4f0cab0a: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.969  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@60d40ff4: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.970  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#0-5] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [rabbitmq:5672]

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.971  WARN 1 --- [ntContainer#1-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.971  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#1-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@6fc6deb7: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.973  WARN 1 --- [ntContainer#1-4] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.973  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#1-4] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@7da39774: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.976  WARN 1 --- [ntContainer#1-3] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.979  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#1-3] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@367f0121: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.979  WARN 1 --- [ntContainer#1-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.979  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#1-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@441b8382: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.982  WARN 1 --- [ntContainer#2-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.982  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#2-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@39bbd9e0: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.984  WARN 1 --- [ntContainer#2-4] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.984  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#2-4] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@4397a639: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.986  WARN 1 --- [ntContainer#2-3] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.986  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#2-3] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@27fe9713: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.988  WARN 1 --- [ntContainer#2-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.988  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#2-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@11c3ff67: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.994  WARN 1 --- [ntContainer#3-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.999  WARN 1 --- [ntContainer#3-3] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.999  WARN 1 --- [ntContainer#3-4] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.999  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#3-3] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@3e4e4c1: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.999  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#3-4] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@46a488c2: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

        2022-03-22 01:07:44.999  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#3-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@3ae126d1: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

        2022-03-22 01:07:45.000  WARN 1 --- [ntContainer#3-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

        2022-03-22 01:07:45.000  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#3-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@7e7f3cfd: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

        2022-03-22 01:07:45.004  WARN 1 --- [ntContainer#4-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

        2022-03-22 01:07:45.005  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#4-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@49d831c2: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

        2022-03-22 01:07:45.008  WARN 1 --- [ntContainer#4-4] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

        2022-03-22 01:07:45.009  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#4-4] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@28bdbe88: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

        2022-03-22 01:07:45.010  WARN 1 --- [ntContainer#4-3] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

        2022-03-22 01:07:45.010  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#4-3] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@43fda8d9: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

        2022-03-22 01:07:45.011  WARN 1 --- [ntContainer#4-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

        2022-03-22 01:07:45.011  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#4-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@53a7a60c: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

        2022-03-22 01:07:45.038  INFO 1 --- [ntContainer#0-5] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#51abf713:45/SimpleConnection@427bde5e [delegate=amqp://rabbitmq@172.23.0.5:5672/, localPort= 54968]
```

I would be very happy if someone could help.
Here is my github repository.
https://github.com/dogaanismail/bank-solution